# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in sql 2016

Tags: sql-server-2008

Below is my SQL query

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYE('', '', '', '', '', convert(DATETIME, getdate()), convert(DATETIME, getdate()), 0
            ) T_TABLE
```

when I ran the above SQL the below exception has been throwed.

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: 1) No need to convert the getdate() as `DATETIME`. 2)What are you trying to do? 3)Is `Employe` the table name?

Comment: @Arulkumar yes Employ the table name , i don't know in which format  i will get date , for testing i am using getdate()

Comment: Then can you share few sample data of the date fields

Comment: it is working when i pass '2017-06-20 18:22:22.633' but when i try to convert it is throwing issue

Comment: check your language setting and read this post https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63643/95107

Comment: i am able to convert "SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-11-13');"
But when i am giving this  CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-11-13') in the above query it is throwing issue

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do here.  You seem confused about what the CONVERT() function does.  `CONVERT(DATETIME, value)` and `CONVERT(DATETIME, value, 0)` are for converting varchars *into* datetimes.  `GETDATE()` is already a datetime.  Try posting the code you're actually having a problem with instead of a simplified example.